# Google Maps Clustering - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google maps in my website and I want to handle multi-markers on maps by using google clustering. I've read the documentation and follow the steps, but the map was not loading when I add a new cluster to the script.

I'm new to google maps API and I want to add the clustering feature to my website.Thanks for any help.

```
   function initMainMap() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom:5,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("main-map"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        // Multiple Markers
        var markers = [
            ['Test, Test', 33.890396,35.506160],
            ['Test, Test', 33.880007,35.514207],
            ['Test, Test', 33.880007,35.518207],
            ['Berytech Al Mathaf, Beirut', 33.880307,35.514507],
            ['Berytech Al Mathaf, Beirut', 33.880407,35.516607]
        ];

        // Info Window Content
        var infoWindowContent = [
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Test</h3>' +
            '<p>Test</p>' +        '</div>'],
            ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Test</h3>' +
            '<p>Test</p>' +
            '</div>']
        ];

        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
            bounds.extend(position);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0]
            });

            // Allow each marker to have an info window
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));

            // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }

        // Call the resize function for a responsive container
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center);
        });

        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
            this.setZoom(14);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browsers developer tools console?

Comment: no everything is working properly

Comment: except there is no map?

Comment: There is no MarkerClusterer in your code.  What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: There is map..This code os for the map without cluster and it working but I need to add a cluster

Comment: I removed the cluster..I need help in adding it to my code..This code is working but I need to add the cluster to it

Comment: Just adding a cluster works for me, please show us the code where you tried to add a cluster and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/) to your code and add your markers to that.

```
// before the loop
var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {imagePath: "http://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m"});

// inside the loop
markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMainMap() {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  // Display a map on the page
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("main-map"), mapOptions);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;
  var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], {
    imagePath: "http://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m"
  });
  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });
    markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
    // Allow each marker to have an info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
  // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  // Call the resize function for a responsive container
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
  });

  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    this.setZoom(14);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMainMap);

// Multiple Markers
var markers = [
  ['Test, Test', 33.890396, 35.506160],
  ['Test, Test', 33.880007, 35.514207],
  ['Test, Test', 33.880007, 35.518207],
  ['Berytech Al Mathaf, Beirut', 33.880307, 35.514507],
  ['Berytech Al Mathaf, Beirut', 33.880407, 35.516607]
];

// Info Window Content
var infoWindowContent = [
  ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Test 0</h3>' +
    '<p>Test</p>' + '</div>'
  ],
  ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Test 1</h3>' +
    '<p>Test</p>' +
    '</div>'
  ],
  ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Test 2</h3>' +
    '<p>Test</p>' +
    '</div>'
  ],
  ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Test 3</h3>' +
    '<p>Test</p>' +
    '</div>'
  ],
  ['<div class="info_content">' +
    '<h3>Test 4</h3>' +
    '<p>Test</p>' +
    '</div>'
  ]
];

// Display multiple markers on a map
```

```css
html,
body,
#main-map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<div id="main-map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you...It is working fine..just want to ask if I want the map to be responsive and stays centered when the width change, what shall I do?

Comment: That is another question, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)